# Extract links within a navigation div with python scrapy selectors

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am trying to extract all the links within the navigation div            **filterCategoryLevelOne** in [this webpage](http://uk.farnell.com/c/electrical).

I did this successfully with Beautifulsoup and requests as follows:

```
>> import requests
>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>> url='http://uk.farnell.com/c/electrical'
>> response = requests.get(url)
>> soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, "html.parser")
>> mydiv = soup.findAll("nav", { "class" : "filterCategoryLevelOne" })
```

**my_div** gives me list with everything from which I can then extract the href values.

However, if I do the same with a scrapy shell as follows, I get something else:

```
>> scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3; en-us) AppleWebKit/999+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/999.9' http://uk.farnell.com/c/electrical
>> response.xpath('//nav[@class="filterCategoryLevelOne"]')
[<Selector xpath='//nav[@class="filterCategoryLevelOne"]' data='<nav class="filterCategoryLevelOne" aria'>]
```

How do I further find the href values within that div in scrapy ?

Comment: Did you try `extract()` or `extract_first()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get directly all the urls with:

```
  response.xpath('//nav[@class="filterCategoryLevelOne"]//a/@href').extract()
```